Save many model in foreach too slow
I am building the e-commerce application, I have struggled to this problem when save many of variants:
Supposedly, I got a request return the collection:
let data = {     
    "_token"    :"{{ csrf_token() }}",     
    "data"  : tableToJson($(".fixed-table table"), $(".scroll-table table")), // return data
}
let res = $.post(url, data); 

It will result like this (in this case, I using with variant with 2 maximum options):
data = {
{
    color: black,
    size: 10,
    sku: abxc,
    quantity: 1,
    price: 100$,
    
},
{
    color: blue,
    size: 10,
    sku: abxz,
    quantity: 2,
    price: 1100$,
},
,....}

I intended to insert in controller with the function:
function insertVariant(Request $request) {
    $datas = $request->all();
    
    $options = new Options();
    $id = options->insertGetId(
            [
                'name'=>'$data['color'] ,
            ]
            , 
            [
                'name'=>'$data['size'] ,
            ]
        ]);

    foreach ($datas in $data) {

        $sku = new SKU();
        $sku['name'] = $data['sku'],
        $sku['price'] = $data['price'],
        $sku['quantity'] = $data['quatity']
        $sku->save();
        
        $variant_value = new VariantValue();
        $variant_value['variant_options_id'] = $id[0];
        $variant_value['value'] = $data['color'];
        $variant_value['value'] = $data['size'];
        $variant_value->save();
        
        $sku_variant_value = new SKUVariantValues();
        $sku_variant_value['variant_value_id'] = $variant_value->id;
        $sku_variant_value['sku_id'] = $sku->id;
        $sku_variant_value->save();
    }    
}

I see that request return too long as though its success?
how can I optimize when save multiple model in foreach with less cost as less as possible?
EDIT:
I am using the database as suggestion: Modeling Product Variants

$options = new Options(); seems useless inside foreach() so remove it

Also $variant_value['value'] = $data['color'];         $variant_value['value'] = $data['size']; don't you think it will overwrite and you will get only one data

I think you need to edit your example code to something that can more closely show the issue you have. The code you shared is wrong, it's seems that you made an effort to cut the problem down to a minimal example (which is good), but your cut-down version is not valid code and has parts that don't make any sense (e.g.  $id = options->insertGetId seems out of place in the code).

Assumption: I am assuming that all tables have auto-incremented id column(primary key)
Reference is taken from : Bulk insert and get returned ids laravel
Here is the code suggested by me:
function insertVariant(Request $request) {
    $datas = $request->all();

    $id = $options->insertGetId(
        [
            'name'=>'$data['color'] ,
        ]
        , 
        [
            'name'=>'$data['size'] ,
        ]
    ]); // check that $options is created and a valid object

    // 1- get the last id of your table SKU say $lastIdBeforeInsertionInSkuTable
    // 2- get the last id of your table VariantValue say $lastIdBeforeInsertionInVariantValueTable


    $skuArray = []
    $variantValueArr = [];

    foreach ($datas in $data) {    
          $sku = [
             'name' => $data['sku'],
             'price' => $data['price'],
             'quantity' => $data['quantity'],
          ];

         $skuArray[] = $sku;
         
         //Using value1 and value 2 because the same index values got over-written, so check and fix it at your end
         $variantValue = [
            'variant_options_id' => $id[0],
            'value1' => $data['color'],
            'value2' = $data['size'],
         ];
         $variantValueArr[] = $variantValue;
    }

    SKU::insert($skuArray);
    VariantValue::insert($variantValueArr);

    $skuIds = [];
    $variantValueIds = [];
    for($i=1; $i<=count($skuArray); $i++){
        $skuIds[] = $lastIdBeforeInsertionInSkuTable+$i;
        $variantValueIds[] = $lastIdBeforeInsertionInVariantValueTable+$i;
    }

    $skuVariantValuesArr = [];
    foreach($skuIds as $key=>$skuId){
        $skuVariantValuesArr[] = [
            'variant_value_id' =>$variantValueIds[$key],
            'sku_id' =>$skuId
        ];
    }
    SKUVariantValues::insert($skuVariantValuesArr);
}

Note: Read the comments inside the code carefully and work accordingly.

You are inserting data for every iteration it may take some time to store every insertsertion. First, need to prepare data in a single array. Then insert the data outside the loop.
$skuArray = []


foreach ($datas in $data) {    
      $sku = [
         'name' => $data['sku'],
         'price' => $data['price'],
         'quantity' => $data['quantity'],
      ];

     $skuArray[] = $sku;
}

SKU::insert($skuArray ); 


It will work. I have tried before that 10K data and also a problem is multiple data comes in a single array. So we need to prepare the data first.

It won't work due to this $sku_variant_value['variant_value_id'] = $variant_value->id;         $sku_variant_value['sku_id'] = $sku->id;. he want each model saved record id to save data of third model.

I have built the code for a single model. But we can convert this multiple model.
